# Website not rendering correctly inside Telegram App

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, telegram

I'm currently working on a website for my company. It works fine on every platform and screen size. However, when I try to open it inside the Telegram App on my mobile device (e.g. clicking on the link inside a chat opens the site in an internal Webview of the app) the styling is completely off.

When I open other websites they look fine. What am I doing wrong? It looks like it is not loading the CSS properly.

I'm not using very complex styling or any libs besides jQuery. The website is pretty straight forward using only basic HTML and CSS functionality.

Opening the page in any regular browser is working fine. I thought that maybe the internal Telegram Browser is not supporting modern CSS, but opening any other page works normally, so I really don't understand what is happening here.

I did not try any other in-App browsers, but I suspect the same behaviour.

Link to the website (still in development):
https://intense-studios.com/newpage/

Comment: You forgot to share the code involved

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem: My Telegram app was caching an old version of the website I opened a few days ago. Although I deleted the app cache on my phone it seems that you cannot delete the cache of the in-app browser.
I tried it on another phone and it worked perfectly.

PS: If somebody knows how to clear the in-app browser cache I'd be more than happy to know.